# How to connect RabbitVCS to SVN server?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, svn, rabbitvcs

I installed RabbitVCS using the Ubuntu Software Center but don't see how to make it connect to my SVN server. I would think that a right click on a folder would bring RabbitVCS up as an option but don't see any reference to RabbitVCS in the right click context menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a section about that in the troubleshooting section ( http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/support/faq ) under **I have installed RabbitVCS, but I don't see any context menu items or emblems!**.  It leads to the support page [here](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/support/known-issues).